# Is this a fine way of validating a client certificate

Tags: .net, ssl, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I need to do a validation of a client certificate, and I am a bit uncertain if I am doing it the right way. My strategy is:

1. see if I can build a chain
2. check the built chain, to see if it matches what I know is true (leaf cert has the same issuer as the intermediate, there is three certs in the chain etc.)

I do an `Issuer` and a chain length check, because I did some unit tests, that did show that if I just sent in the *public key part* of either the

- `root certificate` or
- the `intermediate certificate`

the chain was built successfully, so I couldn't rely on the chain build alone, and that is why I am doing some additional checks, but now I am not certain if this is the right way. I am not checking for revocation, because I know that the `CA` does not provide that currently (It looks like their CRL is expired. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693164/crl-is-expired-but-chainstatus-is-telling-me-revocationstatusunknown)).

Here is my code

```cs
public ChainValidatorStatus Validate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificateToBeValidated)
{
    var chain = new X509Chain();

    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(_options.CA);
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(_options.Intermediate);

    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

    try
    {
        var buildValid = chain.Build(clientCertificateToBeValidated);
        var status = new ChainValidatorStatus { BuildValid = buildValid };

        if (buildValid)
        {
            var buildClientCert = chain.ChainElements.First();

            // there needs to be three elements in the ChainElements. We expect there to be: root, intermediate, client certificate
            var isThereThreeElementsInChainElements = chain.ChainElements.Count == 3;

            // we expect the first cert in the built chain to have an issuer that is the same as the intermediate
            var validIssuerInFirstCertificateInChain = buildClientCert.Certificate.Issuer == _options.Intermediate.Subject;

            // we expect the incoming to have the issuer as the intermediate
            var validIssuer = clientCertificateToBeValidated.Issuer == _options.Intermediate.Subject;

            X509ChainElementCollection elements = chain.ChainElements;
            bool isRootCertTheSame = elements[^1].Certificate.RawData.SequenceEqual(_options.CA.GetRawCertData());

            status.ValidIssuerInFirstCertificateInChain = validIssuerInFirstCertificateInChain;
            status.ValidIssuer = validIssuer;
            status.IsThereThreeElementsInChainElements = isThereThreeElementsInChainElements;
            status.IsRootCertTheSame = isRootCertTheSame;

        }

        // if we get here we know: the client cert is trusted, is signed by the intermediate, and is not the CA or the intermediate
        return status;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return ChainValidatorStatus.NotValid;
    }
}
```

Am I completely off here, or is this a valid way of making sure that:

1. the client certificate is one I trust (by building the chain)
2. the incoming certificate is not the root or the intermediate (by checking the issuer and the chain length)
3. the incoming certificate is signed (or produced by?) the intermediate (by checking the Issuer)

Hope someone will be able to chip in.

Comment: Building your own certificate validation logic should be regarded similarly to building your own crypto. It's very difficult to get right and mistakes can be disastrous. If at all possible you should use some existing validation logic. I don't know .Net well enough to know what is there but they must have something you can leverage. The only part you might need to customize is the very last piece, the authorization/authentication logic. That is, given this otherwise valid client certificate, is this entity allowed to proceed to access the resource?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I am using the builtin primitive in .NET to validate the certificate chain, `X509Chain`. If the call to `.Build` is returning `true`, i know i have a valid chain, but what i have done extra, is to make sure that the certificate coming is built from the intermediate, and isn't the ca or intermediate. If i didnt do that, the intermediate could be sent to me, and my `.Build` would return a valid chain which isn't what i am looking for. I am not trying to build `my own crypto`, but i do want to make sure a bad actor dont just sent in the intermediate. Is there any other way?

Comment: A bad (or good) actor can't just *send* a certificate, they must also perform a private key operation (a signature) to show they possess the private key for the certificate. They're not going to have the private key for any well-known CA certificate or any of the intermediates. Are you you're own CA?

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions here. The chain can be more or less than three. There is no need to check the CA cert is correctly pinned if the intermediate is pinned already. To check if the cert is the same, you don't need to compare the whole cert, just compare the `Thumbprint`. None of your checks actually need to be made at all, as the `X509Chain` is already only using the custom store.

Comment: You say "I do an Issuer check, because I did some tests, that did show that if I just sent in the root certificate or the intermediate certificate, the chain was built successfully, so I couldn't rely on the chain build alone" but this makes no sense, as I said, because if the leaf cert is signed by the intermediate then the root makes no difference (because you have already trusted the intermediate). So why do you need to know who the root is? The intermediate cert defines that.

Comment: @Charlieface i get your point about the extra checks, but i have some unit tests for this, and if i supply the intermediate cert to the `X509Chain.Build` it will return `true`, so i somehow need to check that i don't just receive the intermediate, so that is why i am making that `Issuer` check. How should i be able to tell if i am actually receiving a client certificate, if i am not doing the `Issuer` check?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "don't just receive the intermediate" that's not how it works. You receive a certificate purporting to be signed by an issuer. It may *or may not* come with attached intermediate signers. You have a custom root store. The chain goes to that store and looks up the signer of this leaf cert. If it's found then good, if not then (assuming the intermediate was supplied or found elsewhere) lookup the signer of the intermediate. Recurse infinitely until you find a trusted root in the store. So if you want to pin the intermediate then do that, otherwise pin the root.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i get your point about the CA. For my tests i have created my own root, intermediate and client cert, and when i send the intermediate certificate to my validator, it will build just fine, so that is why i am making all these extra checks. I dont want other people to just grab the public intermediate certificate and send it to me.

Comment: You can't "grab the intermediate and send it", that would only work if they had access to the intermediate's private key, which they don't. All they have is a leaf cert, which they need to *prove* that they have the private key of, and that it's signed by a root you trust (or that that signer is in turn trusted).

Comment: @Charlieface but if i send in the public part of the intemediate, my validation is going to return true. That is why i am baffled. Many people has access to this, because the CA (actually the service i am integrating with is their own CA), emails the public part of the root and the intermediate to all their customers.

Comment: Well I guess you need to look at whatever is supplying the certificate to be validated, because normal SSL tunnels will do a full private key handshake first, so if that fails you wouldn't have anything to verify. Where do you get this certificate from? Is it from `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`?

Comment: @Charlieface i get it from a callback, the service i am integrating with, is calling. Here they supply a client certificate for me to validate. It is lifted of in a nginx proxy that my service is behind, and sent to me in a header.

Comment: @Charlieface i think where i might be wrong. The ingress that is guarding my service is actually doing a verification of the client, by setting `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client` to `optional`, so the tls stream is validated, before it is sent to my service. What i am talking about, when i say test, is that i some unit tests on the above code, where i just supply the intermediate, and the chain is build, but in the real world, this will never happen, or at least i think. I am really not good at this :D

Comment: So basically all you need to do is add the intermediate to the custom store (and possibly the root if the root is unknown to your machine at large) and then build the chain. Then just verify that the intermediate is in the chain and you're good. You don't need to verify anything else.

Comment: It makes sense. I also now know WHY I do the extra validation. My service is receiving the client cert in a header from the ingress, but my service is also exposed to the public, making the endpoints needing client certificate auth callable by any, and thus an attacker can just send in a certificate that would satisfy the chain build. I know, that TLS don't work out of the box on certain endpoints, but works for the entire host, but this is the setup I am trying to improve. I think I will move client cert to it's own service handling all callbacks so and then create a jwt to talk to my service

Comment: Oh btw, @Charlieface, why do you want to validate that the intermediate is in the built chain? Should that be there if I add the intermediate to the custom store and validate it successfully?

Comment: I suppose you are right, if that's the only trusted root in the custome store you don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509Chain` performs a complete certificate chain validation logic (as described in RFC 5280 §6 and a little-bit more), so your logic in `if (buildValid) {}` condition is redundant and potentially flawed. If you look into RFC, chain building and validation is very complex process and it is extremely unlikely you can replicate the same yourself with same degree of confidence. `X509Chain` implements this for you. I agree with comments, do not roll your own crypto.

what you need to do in that condition block, is to perform actual authentication and authorization. That is, you have to examine leaf certificate, extract identify information and bind it to an account in your identity database. After that you can apply authorization rules to figure out what connected identity can do and what cannot.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't this mean that the basis of trust is established in the TLS step, which in turn produces the public part of the certificate that we can use in authorisation flow. In my case, I receive the cert from a nginx, but the problem is that everyone can call my service, and not only the nginx, which means that all can add a certificate to the header I am expecting the cert in, fx the public part of the intermediate. I am currently redoing all this. I need to make sure only the ingress can call my service, or expose the service, while doing a proper TLS flow with client cert.